# Find out when display powers down/screensaver activated in C#

Tags: c#, windows-messages

In my .NET application I need to perform some action when display is powered down or screensaver is activated - after some period of time as set in power settings.
I found that it is possible using window messages - override `WndProc` method and catch message `SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170`. I tested it in test project and it seems to work (at least turning off part) but in my main project it seems I will not be able to use this approach because I have WinForm which is not visible and messages are arriving only for active windows.

- Is it possible to catch those messages in inactive windows?
- Is there any other way to find out when the display is powering off and screensaver activating in .NET?

Thanks for the answers!